# Console.log using remix

Tags: remix

is there any simple to get console.log in remix.ethereum.org?

```
            if (invest.lastCollectedTime < invest.baseTime){
               console.log("test");
            }
```

In remix console works if type in textbox

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but Hardhat offers a [console.log](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network.html#solidity-console-log) solution. You would have to initialise it in a local project, but you could quickly spin up a Hardhat-powered dev environment with my [Solidity template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template).